# ImportError when moving custom python module between PCs

Tags: python, module, wrapper

I have an algorithm written in C++ that I want to use in ArcGIS. Arc supports python scripting, so I figured I'd write a python wrapper. I built python on my development PC and then built a module (called "delaunay", to calculate Delaunay triangulations) to wrap the algorithm. On that PC I was using cygwin with mingw g++ and put the .dll that I built into /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages. Works fine.

So now I'm trying to get it to work on the PC that I run GIS on. ArcGIS installs python as part of its own installation, so I put the .dll in /Python26/ArcGIS10.0/Lib/site-packages (which is in the sys.path) and tried to import it. I got the following error:

ImportError: No module named delaunay

Renamed delaunay.dll to delaunay.pyd and got this error:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have a feeling it'd work if I put the source on the GIS machine and built and installed it with distutils, but I don't really want to install cygwin or Visual Studio on that machine.

Anyway, I have no idea why I get different messages, what the significance of the messages is, or whether this will work at all (i.e. is the ArcGIS distro of Python incompatible with mine 'cause we used different compilers?)
Also, the dev machine has a Jun 12, 2010 revision of Python 2.6.5 and the GIS machine has a Mar 19, 2010 revision. Maybe that is significant?

Help?

Comment: Are both machines running Windows? Same version?

Comment: Dev machine is Windows XP, GIS machine is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Run python -vvv and you'll see import debug info.

You are probably mixing 32-bit and 64-bit binaries. Binaries from different Python builds are incompatible.

Comment: Install the same (mingw) Python on both the computers? .pyd native dependency .dlls must be also present.

Answer (score 0):

> Renamed delaunay.dll to delaunay.pyd and got this error:
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

This sounds like delaunay.pyd depends on some other dll that is not found.